# Reference to instance implementing protocol with associated types

Tags: generics, swift

### Problem

I followed a [common pattern by Apple](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/230611#983807) (4th reply) to work around the lack of generic protocols: I tried to implement a `GeneratorOf<T>`/`SequenceOf<T>`-like struct which can hold a reference to any instance implementing my `ExampleType` protocol. Since the protocol uses associated types I cannot use it as the type for variables directly and need a wrapper struct.

This worked fine until I came across a generic function. I am not able to create a closure to forward to this function and thus cannot fully implement my wrapper struct as Apple did in `GeneratorOf<T>` and alike.

### Current Status

Here a simplified but incomplete example which compiles fine on Xcode 6.1 GM 2 but lacks the generic function:

```
protocol ExampleType {

    typealias Element

    func functionWithElement(element: Element)
    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S)
}


struct ExampleOf<T>: ExampleType {

    typealias Element = T

    private let _functionWithElement: (T) -> ()
    // how to declare _functionWithSequence?


    init<E: ExampleType where E.Element == T>(_ base: E) {
        _functionWithElement = { base.functionWithElement($0) }
        // how to assign _functionWithSequence?
    }

    func functionWithElement(element: Element) {
        _functionWithElement(element)
    }

    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
        // how to call _functionWithSequence?
    }
}
```

### Naïve Approach

This is how it *should* work, but is obviously not possible in Swift.

```
protocol ExampleType {

    typealias Element

    func functionWithElement(element: Element)
    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S)
}



struct ExampleOf<T>: ExampleType {

    typealias Element = T

    private let _functionWithElement: (T) -> ()
    private let _functionWithSequence: <S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>((S) -> ())
    // ERROR: Only syntactic function types can be generic


    init<E: ExampleType where E.Element == T>(_ base: E) {
        _functionWithElement = { base.functionWithElement($0) }
        _functionWithSequence = { base.functionWithSequence($0) }
    }

    func functionWithElement(element: Element) {
        _functionWithElement(element)
    }

    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S) {
        _functionWithSequence(sequence)
    }
}
```

### Question

How can I work around this limitation?
I don't mind about having casts here and there if it's only inside the wrapper.

Comment: Typealiases may not yet involve generics or protocols that declare associated types.  You'll have to radar for this feature.

Comment: I know there's no straightforward way to do that the moment. Since I don't want to wait half a year for Apple to fix that I'm asking for a workaround to achieve the same result.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't quite catch my meaning: you are forbidden from any quantification among typealiases and member variables because there are literally no rules in Swift's type system to handle it.  If you had even the shadow of existential types or rank-N polymorphism this discussion would be a lot more fruitful.  For now, unfortunately, you're stuck until they iterate further.  Swift's types need reification early and often, and that means spoon-feeding the typechecker or unsafeBitcast()'ing your way around things like this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll play a bit with unsafeBitCast but I'm not very confident that I'll find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrapping the parameter with `SequenceOf<T>`:

```
protocol ExampleType {
    typealias Element

    func functionWithElement(element: Element)
    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Element>(sequence: S)
}

struct ExampleOf<T>: ExampleType {

    private let _functionWithElement: (T) -> ()
    private let _functionWithSequence: (SequenceOf<T>) -> ()

    init<E: ExampleType where E.Element == T>(_ base: E) {
        _functionWithElement = { base.functionWithElement($0) }
        _functionWithSequence = { base.functionWithSequence($0) }
    }

    func functionWithElement(element: T) {
        _functionWithElement(element)
    }

    func functionWithSequence<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) {
        _functionWithSequence(SequenceOf(sequence))
    }
}
```